# Auto fill in text when onclick button in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to do this feature where by when i click on the asp button, i can fill up my forms with the static values I've prepared. Can anyone give an idea on how is it done? I've googled for quite a long time but it doesn't match what I wants.

Thanks. Below is the asp codes:

```
    <div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="txtSalary">Salary</label>
  <div class="controls">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalary" name="txtSalary" placeholder="e.g. 30000" class="input-large" required="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="txtCommision">Commissions/Bonus</label>
  <div class="controls">
      <asp:TextBox  id="txtCommision" name="txtCommision" placeholder="e.g. 20000" class="input-large" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <p class="help-block">Commission/Bonus if any</p>
  </div>
</div>

<asp:Button ID="btnFill" runat="server" Text="Fill Up" OnClick="btnFill_Click" />
```

I'm trying to fill up all the textbox when onclick.

Comment: @JustinHarvey i tried: txtSalary.text = 100; in the onclick even in the cs file
but it doesn't work.

P.S. I'm not very good in programming. so pardon me if i make stupid mistakes

Comment: @qU3st When assigning  a value to a text box/ labels it must be a string. 100 is not in string format. txtSalary.text = "100"; should work

Comment: @qU3st It is not about programming. It is about searching. Things can be done easily by searching if you know what you want.

Comment: @JoeW I've tried what u said but still can't work.

Comment: @MxR i tried searching but they all showed html. what i need is asp

Comment: @qU3st How you are storing your static values? In form of Dictionary or you are getting from database??

Comment: If you could post a portion of your aspx code and .cs code we might be able to give a little more help

Comment: @JoeW I've posted the codes

Comment: Are you getting validation message on button click for txtSalary? If yes then refer my answer you need to remove required attribute from txtSalary tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily create the onclick event by double clicking your button in the design view.

or you can manually create it:

```
protected void btnFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSalary.Text = "100";
    txtCommision.Text = "20";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple you just need to add EventHandler for Button click event. You can add it from design via property panel (event section) double click on click event which will add EventHandler for click event. Write your auto fill code inside generated method inside code behind file (Default.aspx.cs).

For more information to add click EventHandler, refer [This Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Or you can add eventhandler dynamically.

Like,

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnFill.Click += new EventHandler(btnFill_Click);
        }

        void btnFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtSalary.Text = "200";
        }
```

In your code you set `txtSalary` as required field so, if you want to fill value in that text box you need to remove required attribute from `txtSalary` otherwise it's will display validation message on button click.

```
<div class="controls">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalary" name="txtSalary" placeholder="e.g. 30000" class="input-large" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
```